# How do I show German characters rendered correctly?

Tags: utf-8

I have an issue that is elsewhere on this website, though I don't see a way to add a comment to it, without being asked to "answer" it.

My website was originally created NOT using UTF-8.  We are updating them all now.  But late, I know.

But now the German site we built, has this issue of the German characters showing the black diamonds.

We cannot add the longer 'code' for each character as they are words typed into products and menu links.  So I assume we have to update our database.  I have done this setting it to "utf8_germany2_ci".

I use notepad or notepad2 for writing code. It says "ANSI" in the baseline of the window.

I've read that using "cp850" might be better, but I've not heard of it before now.

Happy to supply screenshots and make any alterations.

Comment: Is your page also written in PHP? If yes, set the `content-language` header in php: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: Hi.  Yes it is.  This is the very top of the index.php file:
<?php 
// de
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: An example is we have tried to validate a page, but we get this message: " Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 44 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8 (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.

The error was: utf8 "\xFC" does not map to Unicode "

Comment: it seems it's a little bit too late to render it automatically (_If i'm not wrong_).

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your point?  I can see the text in the database and in phpmyadmin they show up as they should.  It's just the rendering on my screen on the website, and in the "rendered" source code.

Comment: UPDATE: If I create a test.html file and put in a German word like this "ausgefüllt", and save it.  It renders fine.

If I use this, I get the diamond:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-de">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
ausgefüllt
</body>
</html>

Comment: Just because your HTML uses a `<meta>` tag to *claim* that it is using UTF-8 does not *guarantee* that it really is.  Whatever tool you are using to create and save the HTML file needs to actually *produce* UTF-8 in the file. For example, if you use Windows' standard Notepad, make sure you tell it to save the file as UTF-8 and not as ANSI. You even said "*I use notepad or notepad2 for writing code. It says **"ANSI"** in the baseline of the window*", so clearly you are not actually working in UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you.  I found out yesterday my tool to create, was NOT using utf-8.  It now is.  But the data entered was not entered using that.  So how do I update all content, so that it is stored with utf8?  As even if save an internal file using utf8, and echo content from the db, it shows it with the funny characters.  I have run an update on the DB, and each field is "utf8_general_ci".  That's not to say the content in there was added with that.  So how do I update the lot??

Comment: I've just updated a product using this code, but in the older HTML format they show as: Akkus and LadegerÃ¤te set .
This worries me.  In the Database I can see this: "UmrÃ¼stsÃ¤tze".
It renders ok, but is that right????